# How to fix ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) in Python?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I have a dataset called `records`, a dataset sample looks like:

```
first_record = records[0]
print(first_record)
_____________________________
['1', '1001', 'Movie']
```

I would like to extract each value for further computation, and when I do the following code:

```
for user, item, tag in first_record :
    print(user, item, tag)
```

I am having this error:

```
----> 1 for user, item, tag in first_record :
      2     print(user, item, tag)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

How can I extract each value corresponding to my user, item, tag variables in the dataset?

Comment: I think you wanted to iterate over records, and not first_record

Comment: Are you sure of your example code ? The message should say `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1), because the string '1' has only 1 digit, not 2 and python is trying to send character of each string of first_record to variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to iterate over 1D list, hence the problem. You can convert it into a 2D list like so

```
first_record = [records[0]]
```

Then you should be able to iterate

```
for user, item, tag in first_record :
    print(user, item, tag)
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comment, if you're using just record[0] then it's best not to iterate, rather assign the values directly like so

```
user, item, tag = first_record
print(user, item, tag)
```

Comment: Why iterate if there's only one item?

Comment: It depends on OP's usage, I just mentioned the flaw

Comment: The way to fix it is to get rid of the iteration, just write `user, item, tag = first_record`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you meant to iterate over `records`, not `first_record` (the first element in the `records` list), and for each record print those three values:

```py
for user, item, tag in records:
    print(user, item, tag)
```

Comment: Thank you, when I run that I have the following error, how to fix it?                               `----> 1 for user, item, tag in records:
      2     print(user, item, tag)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Answer (score 2):

if first_record only has these 3 elements you can directly assign variable as follows:

```
first_record = ['1', '1001', 'Movie']                                                                               
user,item,tag = first_record                                                   
print (user,item,tag)
```